# My custom login form in Django attempts to create a new user rather than log a user in

Tags: django, python-3.x

I set up a custom user class and I'm using all custom user management templates, views, urls, etc... All of them work except my login view. I can get it to work by pulling taking the username and password straight from the request and skipping form cleaning. That however, sounds like a really bad idea.

When I try to use forms.is_valid() The function gives me errors indicating it's trying to create a new user rather than log an existing one in. I've been looking around and doing trial and error for a few hours now and I still have no clue why its doing this and why no one seems to be concerned about cleaning their login forms.

Here is my login view:

```
def loginView(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST)
            authError = False
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                post = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username)
                if post:
                    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    authError = True
            print("form failed")
            #print(form)
            #print(form.errors)
            return render(request, 'login.html', context={'form': form, 'form_errors': form.errors, "auth_error": authError})
        else:
            print("get request")
            form = forms.LoginForm()
            print(form)
            return render(request, 'login.html', context={'form': form})
    else:
        return redirect('home')
```

and here is my form:

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        widgets = {'password': forms.PasswordInput()}
```

Comment: Don't use a `ModelForm` because your login form isn't editing/creating a user. Just use a plain `Form` where you define a `username` and `password` field.

Comment: Look at `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` for inspiration. The form's `clean()` method not only cleans the fields but actually authenticates the user and verifies that the user is allowed to login (`is_active`). So a view only has to perform the `login` once the form is valid.